# How To Update TextBox using Update panel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I Have a `TextBox` outside the `UpdatePanel` and a `Button` inside the `Updatepanel` When i click on the `Button` it show value in `TextBox`.

I Have Write Following Code.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="AjaxToolKit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"         
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
         EnablePageMethods="true" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Up1">
       <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" onclick="btn_Click" />
       </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

----------Code Behind---------

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox5.Text = "20000";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your textbox value can't be updated untill you put it in an update panel.

```
<ContentTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" onclick="btn_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

OR, it would be better if you register a trigger of the button and pull your button out from your update, like...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnl" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: yah, whatI have told you, that value only update if that particular control is in update panel.