# How can i get the values of asp textbox control in UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I got a trouble with my ascx control. I cannot get the values of textbox normally when it in an Updatepanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            <button type="button" runat="server" id="btnCreateDomain" onserverclick="btnCreateDomain_ServerClick" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In code, in the "btnCreateDomain_ServerClick" function, i wrote as below to get value of this textbox:

```
string desc = txtDescription.Text;
```

But the values always return is empty value! 
Who can help me?

Comment: try to refer this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896807/how-to-update-textbox-using-update-panel-in-asp-net

Comment: Have you tried with asp button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and there is mistakes. so try following code. It works for me.

```
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCreateDomain" OnClick="btn_click" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Save"></asp:Button>

                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in .cs file,

```
     protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string desc = txtDescription.Text;
    }
```